# Is it possible to rename a directory in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, directory, rename

In SSIS is it possible to rename a directory? There is a requirement like copy a directory and paste it in a different location and rename it with current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in SSIS using the `File System Task`.

For detail and step by step visit [this link](http://oops-solution.blogspot.com/2011/11/file-operation-copy-move-rename-and.html).